# Implement an array of string with elements of varying size

Tags: c++, string

How to implement an array of strings with different sizes, i.e. an array `stringar[4]={"black","red","blue","green"}`.
Also, how to access individual letters/characters of each element in C++?
Edit:
This is what I tried in CPP. But it gives the same output (i.e. 0) for all inputs. 
code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   int n,i,j,p,q,f=0,count=0,key,m;
    char s[100][100];
    cin>>n;
    for( i = 0; i < n; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < 100; j++)
        cin >> s[i][j];
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 100; j++) 
            {
                key = s[i][j];
                for (p = i + 1; p < n; p++) 
                {
                    for (q = 0; q < m; q++) 
                    {
                        if (key == s[p][q]) {f = 1;break;}
                        else {f = 0;continue;}
                    }
                }
                if (f == 1)
                    count++;
            }
        }
    cout<<count;        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does using `std::vector<std::string>` count as "implementing" it for you?

Comment: If your question is answered, please mark it as 'answered', PGreen_xyz.

Comment: I am actually new to use stackoverflow. So how to mark it as answered? @Trantor

Comment: Navigate to the particular answer you consider solved your problem best, at the left side are the Up/Down "arrows" and the counter. Below, there is a hook you can set and unset to mark "the" answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, you need to imagine that as a **Matrix** with variable sizes.

`[b][l][a][c][k]`

`[r][e][d]`

`[b][l][u][e]`

`[g][r][e][n]`

```
 std::vector<std::string> stringar;
    stringar.push_back( "black" );
    stringar.push_back( "red" );

    char letter = stringar[ 0 ][ 1 ]; 
    char letter2 = stringar[ 1 ][ 2 ];
```

`letter`will have the letter in position 1 of the array in the matrix of position 0:

**Array in position 0: `black`. letter in position 1: `l`**

**Array in position 1: `red`. Letter in position 2: `d`**

`[b][l][a][c][k]`

`[r][e][d]`

**Edit:**

As you asked me in the comments, here it is a rough implementation, so you can see how it is done! (excuse my `printf`instead of `cout`but I was not able to use it.

```
int rows = 4; //black, red, blue, green ==> 4 elements
    int cols[4] = { 5, 3, 4, 5 }; // 5 letters for black, 3 letters for red, etc.
    int** matrix = new int*[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        matrix[i] = new int[cols[i]];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols[i];j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
            printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

This will show this output, that is what you are looking for (instead of `0`s, whatever minerals you need).

`00000 (black)
 000   (red)
 0000  (blue)
 00000 (green)`

[image: The output:]

Comment: This was really helpful. Actually the question I was solving is as follows: A mineral is called a gemstone if it occurs at least once in each of the rocks in the array collection.

Given a list of minerals embedded in each of John's rocks, display the number of types of gemstones he has in his collection.

For example, the array of mineral composition strings arr=[abc,abc,bc] The minerals b and c appear in each composite, so there are 02 gemstones.

Comment: So, can you put more insight into the approach to be adopted to solve this problem?

Comment: wouldn't there be 3 gemstones and not 2? as abc, abc and bc, all three have b and c, right? Let's get the question right then: a mineral can be called, for example "abc", AND it is a gemstone if it contains, X in it, for example, a, or b, or c in this case right? @PGreen_xyz

Comment: Yes, I am really sorry i couldn't post the full question because of limit. So, each element in the array(abc,abc,a) defines the composition of a rock. Here a,b,c individually are different minerals in the rock. Since b and c are the only minerals present in each rock, b and c are gemstones. So there are two gemstones (b and c).

Comment: Remember, this is a "matrix" (well, it is and it is not, but to understand it better, it is). So to access the members, a double loop  would be the thing(first loop for each word, second loop for each character of the word). **CARE**, the problem here is the length of the second loop, as it varies. You could change that at the end of the 1st loop, once every iteration of the second has been done! I'll try to implement it tomorrow, but try it by yourself today! @PGreen_xyz

Comment: How can I add my code to this comment, since it exceeds the word limit?

Comment: I guess editing the question is the thing to do @PGreen_xyz . Add: "Edit:" and the code below!

Comment: I have added the code in the question. Can you check and suggest the error?

Comment: I have added the code in the question. Can you check and suggest the error?

Comment: I edited my answer like 5 mins ago, check the implementation @PGreen_xyz

Comment: Probably that quadruple `for`loop is complicating things. Try debugging, as it will show you EVERY step and variable value you need to know, to know what's happening. @PGreen_xyz

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
std::vector<std::string> VectorOfStrings;
VectorOfStrings.push_back( "blue" );
VectorOfStrings.push_back( "red" );

char letter = VectorOfStrings[ 1 ][ 0 ]; // access 'r'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the strings and individual characters in a number of ways. Here are three examples:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // dynamic array-like collection of strings:
    std::vector<std::string> stringar = {"black","red","blue","green"};

    // access using index
    for(size_t vidx = 0; vidx<stringar.size(); ++vidx) {
        std::cout << "Accessing the contents of " << stringar[vidx] << "\n";
        for(size_t sidx = 0; sidx<stringar[vidx].size(); ++sidx) {
            std::cout << " " << stringar[vidx][sidx] << "\n";
        }
    }

    // access using iterators
    for(std::vector<std::string>::iterator vit = stringar.begin(); vit!=stringar.end(); ++vit) {
        std::cout << "Accessing the contents of " << *vit << "\n";
        for(std::string::iterator sit = (*vit).begin(); sit!=(*vit).end(); ++sit) {
            std::cout << " " << *sit << "\n";
        }
    }

    // access using range based for loop
    for(const auto& str : stringar) {
        std::cout << "Accessing the contents of " << str << "\n";
        for(auto ch : str) {
            std::cout << " " << ch << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```